# "More can be done yet" - correct use and position of the word "yet"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I want to say, despite the good progress, there are more that can be done.

Are the following use and position of the word "yet" correct and convey the intended message?

"More can be done yet." or

"More to be done yet." - seem like an incomplete sentence.

"More is yet to be done." - seem less impactful.

Comment: I think you could use: "Yet more can be done." "[And] Yet, more can be done." "More, yet, can be done." "More can yet be done." "More can be done yet."  English is pretty flexible here.

Comment: @Jim: Yup that's what I thought too. Do you agree with my analysis of the third variant in the question?

Comment: I read your third one as meaning “our current plan is to do more; we just haven’t got there yet.”. Note that it uses ***is*** rather than ***can*** like the others which changes things more than the placement of *yet*.

Comment: Updated to reflect the intended question.
Answer by @user21820 addressed the question and I'm accepting it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In present-day idiomatic English it is usually:

> Still/Yet more can be done.

Your variant in the title of your question would be easily understood and is grammatically correct, however it has a slight archaic/poetic feel:

> More can be done yet. [The "yet" adverbially modifies the whole sentence.]

Your second variant is grammatically incorrect:

> (WRONG) More to be done yet. [This is not a complete sentence because it lacks a main verb.]

Your third variant is grammatically correct but strikes me as a little unusual:

> More is yet to be done.

Perhaps other native speakers might interpret this the way you intend, but I personally feel there's a slight difference, since this seems to convey that more will be done, whereas presumably you only intend to convey just the possibility that more can be done.